# Retrieve partner_id in onchange() function Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I want to retrieve "id" actually partner. 
With my function, I use `onchange()` decorator but, for it to work, I have to put the hard value.

I have tried:

```
print self.partner_id.id
print self.partner_id
```

It sends me :

```
<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fa382596090>
res.partner(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fa382596090>
```

Here my function :

```
# Récupère le foyer actif
@api.onchange('foyer_members')
def _get_active_foyer(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.foyer_members:
            print self.partner_id.id
            print self.partner_id
            records_foyer_id = self.env['horanet.relation.foyer'].search([('partner_id', '=', 145536)], limit=1)
            print records_foyer_id
```

My fields :

```
partner_id = fields.Many2one(string="Child", comodel_name="res.partner")

foyer_members = fields.Many2one(string='Foyers members',
                                comodel_name="res.partner",
                                ondelete='restrict',
                                domain="[('company_type','=','foyer')]",
                                delegate=False)
```

How to do it? Thank You!